# Win32: CredUIConfirmCredentials behaves unexpectedly

Tags: windows, security, credentials, credui

I'm using [CredUIConfirmCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375173.aspx) in combination with 
[CredUIPromptForCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375177.aspx).

[I](http://www.secnewsgroups.net/dotnet/t143-creduiconfirmcredentials-behaves-unexpectedly.aspx) set the `EXPECT_CONFIRMATION`, and when the credentials are **first** provided by 
the user the call to `CredUIConfirmCredentials` returns **NO_ERROR** as expected.

However, on all subsequent calls to `CredUIConfirmCredentials`, with the same 
credentials, **ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER** is returned. This is described by [the 
SDK docs as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/secauthn/security/creduiconfirmcredentials.asp):

> An attempt to confirm a waiting
>   credential failed because the
>   credential  contained invalid or
>   inconsistent data.

which is rather confusing as they are exactly the same credentials that were successfully saved originally.

The same result is returned if you enter a **different** password for the same 
username. What is even more confusing is that the new credentials are 
actually persisted - which seems to indicate that the return value is 
actually indicating that the persisted credentials were overwritten - not 
that there was a error. Am I missing something, or is the documentation 
incorrect?

---

### Background

You can use Window's credential system to store credentials for your own application. You tell Windows you want to prompt for "*generic*" credentials for some "*target*":

pseudo-code:

```
CredUIPromptForCredentials("My Application", ref username, ref password);
```

will then cause Windows to display a dialog box:

[image]

It is then your job to check the credentials the user has entered. If they are valid, you tell Windows this by calling **ConfirmCredentials**. This is to ensure that only valid credentials are saved:

```
CredUIConfirmCredentials("My Application", true);
```

Once the credentials have been confirmed as valid, Windows will save them in the secure store, which you can see through the Control Panel:

[image]

Keywords: credui, CredUIConfirmCredentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer: by design

`CredUIConfirmCredentials` will return an error "when there's nothing to do". This means:

- if the credentials are the same as what's already in the credential store
- the user didn't check the `Rembember my password` check box
- you didn't set the `CREDUI_FLAGS_EXPECT_CONFIRMATION` flag

The fact that `CredUIConfirmCredentials` fails when the credentials are the same as what's already in the store documented on MSDN. (i know it's documented because i added to [the documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)